# Building Python3 Twisted module in yocto project

Tags: yocto

- When trying to build the python twisted module using the recipe.
- I have the runtime dependencies python recipes.
- I don't have an idea about the error to add a native recipe since I don't have such an incremental-native recipe file.

```
inherit pypi setuptools3

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=27ac6d9597237e7e76282edd7a40cd68"

SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "d72c55b5d56e176563b91d11952d13b01af8725c623e498db5507b6614fc1e10"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "Twisted" 
PYPI_PACKAGE_EXT = "tar.bz2"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = " ${PYTHON_PN}-zope-interface ${PYTHON_PN}-incremental ${PYTHON_PN}-constantly \
                   ${PYTHON_PN}-hyperlink ${PYTHON_PN}-pyhamcrest ${PYTHON_PN}-attrs "
```

- Getting error, add native recipes to DEPENDS.

````
ERROR: python3-twisted-20.3.0-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/pravin/yocto-project/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-twisted/20.3.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.179353' failed with exit code 1:
WARNING: The pip package is not available, falling back to EasyInstall for handling setup_requires/test_requires; this is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
ERROR: Do not try to fetch `incremental>=16.10.1' for building. Please add its native recipe to DEPENDS.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pravin/yocto-project/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-twisted/20.3.0-r0/Twisted-20.3.0/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    setuptools.setup(**_setup["getSetupArgs"]())
  File "/home/pravin/yocto-project/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-twisted/20.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/home/pravin/yocto-project/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-twisted/20.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 157, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "/home/pravin/yocto-project/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-twisted/20.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 699, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "/home/pravin/yocto-project/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/python3-twisted/20.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 785, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'incremental>=16.10.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.```
````

Comment: There exists an python3-twisted recipe upstream. Which version did you use? https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/109096/

Comment: latest Twisted 20.3.0